# static methods in Java EE

Tags: static, ejb

Assume I have a Java EE Scenario and I want to implement a simple MathResource with methods like public int add(int x, int y). Now I could just provide a simple class with static methods for this, I don't even need any objects. Is there any reason why I should make this MathResource a stateless session bean or a singleton session bean instead?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.
(Simple Question, simple Answer, but the "at least 30 Character" forces me to write more Text.)